# What is needed to run a Delphi 4 program

Tags: windows-7, delphi

When running a java program I would have to have the jre in the path/installed
What is the equivalent in Delphi 4? is there any run-time to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi 4 programs are compiled to native code and run in Windows without a runtime engine (such as .NET and Java use). It may require additional resources such as libraries (DLL's), but that is specific to each application.